# Writing a JSX.IntrinsicElements type with dynamic attributes based on the value of another attribute

Tags: typescript

I am attempting to create a type for a custom element in the JSX.IntrinsicElements interface, so that when using my custom element, correct intellisense is produced for the attributes. This works great in simple cases, but I have an advanced use case that doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my attempt at a solution:

```
type MyButton = { label?: any };
type MyText = { text?: any };

interface ControlTypes {
  button: MyButton,
  text: MyText
}

type MyControlType<K extends keyof ControlTypes> = { id?: any, type?: K } & ControlTypes[K];

declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      'my-control': MyControlType
    }
  }
}
```

The idea here is that when the 'type' attribute is a certain value, more props are exposed based on the value of 'type'.

For example, if I have `<my-control type="button" />`, I expect the 'label' attribute to now show up in intellisense. When I have `<my-control type="text" />`, I expect the 'text' attribute to show up.

This does not work in VS Code or WebStorm. I'm not sure if I have incorrect TypeScript, or the IDEs are simply not smart enough to support this use case.